# How to query a website that (I think) uses javascript in data table?

Tags: javascript, excel

I use Excel to query web pages for data to analyze sports stats (NBA, MLB). Most of the queries have no problem bringing in the data from the web page, but NBA.com gives me a lot of issues. A specific example is http://stats.nba.com/league/player/#!/advanced/ - when I make a web query in Excel, none of the actual player data imports. My question is is there a way for me to dynamically get this data? Also, if the data actually did import, NBA.com splits the data into multiple pages that cannot be combined into one big table. Can I get all the data at once without copying and pasting from the 9+ different table "rows"?

Comment: Yeah I saw that. That sucks man.  You can probably call them and ask if they can provide the data sheet for you in csv format.  It wouldn't take more than 5 clicks of the mouse for them.

Comment: @Rafael: actually, they practically do: http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2014-15&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&VsConference=&VsDivision=